# Does the 'break' keyword prevent the code from running that loop again in Python?

Tags: python, loops, break

Here is my code, in which I try to reference the walls list of tuples in the creation of the map list of tuples, which has the index [variable][2] as the property of being a wall or floor:

```
map = []
walls = [(0,3), (0,4), (0,5), (0,7), (2,7), (3,7), (4,7), (5,7), (1,7),
(5,6), (5,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,5), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (7,0), (7,1), (7,5), 
(7,6), (7,7), (8,7)]
for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        for a in range(len(walls)):
            if walls[a][0] == x and walls[a][1] == y:
                map.append(tuple((x,y,"w")))
            else:
                map.append(tuple((x,y,"_")))
            break

---> [(0, 0, '_'), (0, 1, '_'), (0, 2, '_'), (0, 3, 'w'), (0, 4, '_'), (0, 5, '_'), (0, 6, '_'), (0, 7, '_'), (0, 8, '_'), (1, 0, '_'), (1, 1, '_'), (1, 2, '_'), (1, 3, '_'), (1, 4, '_'), (1, 5, '_'), (1, 6, '_'), (1, 7, '_'), (1, 8, '_'), (2, 0, '_'), (2, 1, '_'), (2, 2, '_'), (2, 3, '_'), (2, 4, '_'), (2, 5, '_'), (2, 6, '_'), (2, 7, '_'), (2, 8, '_'), (3, 0, '_'), (3, 1, '_'), (3, 2, '_'), (3, 3, '_'), (3, 4, '_'), (3, 5, '_'), (3, 6, '_'), (3, 7, '_'), (3, 8, '_'), (4, 0, '_'), (4, 1, '_'), (4, 2, '_'), (4, 3, '_'), (4, 4, '_'), (4, 5, '_'), (4, 6, '_'), (4, 7, '_'), (4, 8, '_'), (5, 0, '_'), (5, 1, '_'), (5, 2, '_'), (5, 3, '_'), (5, 4, '_'), (5, 5, '_'), (5, 6, '_'), (5, 7, '_'), (5, 8, '_'), (6, 0, '_'), (6, 1, '_'), (6, 2, '_'), (6, 3, '_'), (6, 4, '_'), (6, 5, '_'), (6, 6, '_'), (6, 7, '_'), (6, 8, '_'), (7, 0, '_'), (7, 1, '_'), (7, 2, '_'), (7, 3, '_'), (7, 4, '_'), (7, 5, '_'), (7, 6, '_'), (7, 7, '_'), (7, 8, '_'), (8, 0, '_'), (8, 1, '_'), (8, 2, '_'), (8, 3, '_'), (8, 4, '_'), (8, 5, '_'), (8, 6, '_'), (8, 7, '_'), (8, 8, '_')]
```

The issue: Only one coordinate is checked and assigned 'w', while the rest are not. The point of logic where I see the issue would be the break statement. Does the break statement prevent the last nested for loop from running ever again. Should it not go: x=0, y=3, a=0, break ---> x=0, y=4, a=0, a=1, break --->...

Comment: What do you think a `break` does?

Comment: `break` breaks out of the current loop. It does not prevent the loop from being run again (if it is inside another loop). But your innermost loop always breaks in the first iteration because your `break` is not in an `if` statement.

Comment: It is the same if the break statement is within the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From python docs:

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing for or while loop.

Read further in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Hopefully this will help you, Yahli.